# why tcp and net.tcp is not good for internet applications?

Tags: silverlight, tcp, net.tcp

i read the following sentence form *Silverlight Data & Service* book(Chapter 7):
"just like TCP, net.tcp is a good fit for intranet
applications and not for internet applications"
why? what's the problem if i want to use net.tcp binding in my silverlight application over the internet?

Thanks

Comment: The surrounding context of the quote might be enlightening. TCP is a very good fit for many internet applications.

Comment: What a strange notion.  The vast majority of internet traffic works over TCP quite happily...

Comment: The context that should be here is with respect to DNS; using net.tcp for transport in a WCF binding lacks domain name resolution.

Comment: Security issues with the library???  There isn't much else that's different when deploying to one or the other, although even then I'd rather my intranet applications not be filled with exploitable code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These limitations in Silverlight net.tcp reduce its usefulness for internet applications:

- **net.tcp requires ports in the range 4502-4534.** Users behind restrictive firewalls cannot make connections over those ports. However, net.tcp can still be useful as a first try, with fallback to an HTTP binding if the port is blocked. This maintains the client performance and server scalability benefits where possible.
- **net.tcp does not support TLS.**

References:

- MSDN: [Building and Accessing Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645026%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [The duplex story: looking at duplex communication in Silverlight - Part 3: Using Net.Tcp](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-duplex-story-looking-at-duplex-communication-in-Silverlight-4-Part-3-Using-Net.Tcp.aspx)
- [WCF net.tcp protocol in Silverlight 4](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/wcf-nettcp-protocol-in-silverlight-4.html)